# Quick Simple Product Creation doesn't appear

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configurable-product

I would like to create simple products from a configurable product, but the "quick simple product creation" dialog does not appear when I create a new configurable product. The dialog is described here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configurable-product-step-4-add-associated-products

How can I quickly create simple products with the correct options from a configurable product?

Comment: The form appears only after you save the configurable product.

Comment: Thanks. Could you write the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick create form appears only after the initial configurable product is saved